# How can I to close apps from Super+W?

Tags: shortcut-keys

close apps from Super+W
so what I am interested in is if there is a way to close apps from Super+W

like this

[image]

or is there a buton that i can press and the app wil cloas by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can close the highlighted application from the Super+W "spread window" display using Alt+F4.

Comment: many thanks 
maybe not the ideal way but gets the job done